# How to call page down function in Flex DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, pagination, pagedown

I have DataGrid control in Flash Builder, it shows a long list of data.
I want to set a timer, so every time the timer ticks, the timer will call a function which makes the DataGrid control do a pagedown action, just like you click the scroll bar every 3 seconds. What is the easiest way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set verticalScrollPosition of DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Even-though it's not very clear you can try something like this

```
      private var gridTimer:Timer;

      public function onSomeFunction():void
      {
            gridTimer = new Timer(5000); //the timer is set for 5 seconds 
            gridTimer.addEventListener("timer", dataGridTimer);
            gridTimer.start();
      }

      private function dataGridTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
      {
            grid.verticalScrollPosition = value;
      }
```